# Copy a specific sheet to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How would could one write a macro that will copy sheet 2 from workbook 1 and create a new workbook and paste that sheet into the new workbook If i click on a button I have added at the bottom of sheet 1, workbook 1.

**Edit**
This code copies the active sheet(which is not the sheet I want) and does the rest perfectly by prompting to save as, which is cool, However I need to copy sheet 2 and not the active sheet.

```
Sub GetQuote()

   Dim activeWB As String
   Dim thisSheet As String

   activeWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   thisSheet = Workbooks(activeWB).ActiveSheet.Name
   Workbooks.Add
   Workbooks(activeWB).Sheets(thisSheet).Copy _
   Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? give the macro recorder a chance, look at the code and get back if you're stuck! :-)

Comment: I have tried code that copies the active sheet and not sheet two because I have hidden that sheet on purpose. I will edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Sub GetQuote()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```